# Is there Grid align-content: center; for IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-grid

Is there any prefix or old spec grid code for `align-content: center;` that works in **IE11**?

Comment: Better add you full code and what you want to do. Probably there is a different way to do the same without CSS grid

Comment: I know how to do it without grid, I want to do it with grid (Which I also know how, just not sure if it's supported IE11 with prefix) I guess most of the times it's better to post full code, but this one is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Except with your code posted maybe somebody will see another way to do it with CSS Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grid code for **align-content: center;** is not supported in IE browser and there is no prefix or old spec grid code available to fix the issue for IE browser.

[image]

References:

(1) [align-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content)

(2) [Box alignment in CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout)